# java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file while deploying war to websphere

Tags: liferay, websphere

I am trying to deploy my war file to websphere 8 and it's giving me below error.

```
02:02:57,209 INFO  [com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner][Aut             oDeployDir:182] Processing MIR.war. This is attempt 169.
02:02:57,215 ERROR [com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner][Aut             oDeployDir:210] com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployException: java.             util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployException: java.util.zip.ZipExce             ption: error in opening zip file
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.BaseAutoDeployListener.isMatchi             ngFile(BaseAutoDeployListener.java:87)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.BaseAutoDeployListener.isHookPl             ugin(BaseAutoDeployListener.java:43)
        at com.liferay.portal.deploy.auto.HookAutoDeployListener.deploy(HookAuto             DeployListener.java:43)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployDir.processFile(AutoD             eployDir.java:193)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployDir.scanDirectory(Aut             oDeployDir.java:235)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner.run(AutoDeplo             yScanner.java:54)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:150)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:166)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.BaseAutoDeployListener.isMatchi             ngFile(BaseAutoDeployListener.java:72)
        ... 5 more
```

The war is generated by Jenkins maven build.  What's going wrong here ?

Comment: With that amount of information it's hard to say anything beyond "there's an error in your zip/war file". Can you unzip the war file with a command line/UI unzip tool? Also, as it's obviously not Websphere deploying but Liferay: Which version (please be exact) of Liferay are you running?

Comment: It's - liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2

Comment: The issue was with war file only.  Redeployed the war and now everything is working as expected.